# Consider $ ‎\delta = \{ X_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ be a sequence in $[0,1]$ with usual topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider $ ‎\delta = \{ X_n  : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ be a sequence in $[0,1]$ with usual topology.

> Does $\delta $ have a subsequence $\{  x‎_{n‎_{k}‎}‎  : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ that converge to some $x \in [0,1]$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes; this is a consequence of the [Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), which states more generally that a bounded sequence of real numbers has a convergent subsequence. The fact that the limit lies in $[0, 1]$ is due to the fact that $[0, 1]$ is closed.

One way to prove this is to divide the interval into $[1/2, 1]$ and $[0, 1/2]$, noting that one of these intervals contains infinitely many sequence terms. Subdivide that interval into two subintervals of length $1/4$, and continue.

Comment: the Bolzano- Weierstrass Theorem is that  every bounded infinit subset of real numbers has  accumulation point. How can we obtain " there is a converge sequence in $[0,1]$ s.t converge to $x \in X$ by the Bolzano- Weierstrass Theorem ? Please help me.

Comment: So $\delta$ has an accumulation point; try interpreting "accumulation point" in the context of limits.